# VMWare ESX/i 4 SCSI Tape?

Tags: backup, vmware-esxi, tape, tapedrive

Has anyone successfully used SCSI mapping to present a SCSI tape drive to a VM for backup purposes?  My servers do not support VMDirectIO (VT-d), so I can't present the PCI device to the VM, and my Adaptec 39160 is not supported in ESXi4.  Before I spend $300 on a replacement card -- I want to be sure others have even found it possible to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Bought a 39360 for $100 and it works like a charm with SCSI passthrough.

Comment: really, that's interesting, I've never tried to do that myself as we use VCB but good news - what OS and software did you use in the VM to talk to the drive?

Comment: Win2k3, Backup Exec 10, ESXi 4, and ESXi 4u1

Answer (score 1):

I have a Adaptec SCSI Card 29320LPE, using pass-through on ESXi with up-to-date "firmware" (VMware OS). Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It must be in [VMware Compatibility Guide](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php), or you have to use VMDirectPath. No third option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the way to go? VMware doesn't support such configuration and neither several data protection vendors. It can be very tricky to troubleshoot too.

Answer (score 0):

So if you can't do DirectIO how do you plan for your ESXi box to address this tape drive? Don't forget with ESXi there's now COS to load any drivers/code.

Presumably you've got the free version (?) in which case you don't have a VCB license, if so I think you'd be better off backup up via the to a second machine with the tape drive.

Let us know more detail and we'll try to think of some other options ok.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be ideal but why not use a seperate server for backups running say bacula which connects and manages the tape drive. Then install the client on all of the vms. Now you have a decent backup infrastructure. Granted you need another machine but this seems like it may do what you want.